# how to checkin all checked out files via powershell?

Tags: 2013, powershell

We have in our environment installed Gary LaPointe powershell cmdlets and I found this script

```
Get-SPCheckedOutFiles
```

which returns all checkedout files, now I need to forcely check them in,  not sure how to do though that in powershell.

http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2011/06/getting-and-taking-ownership-of-checked-out-files-using-windows-powershell/

Comment: You want to checkin aa files in site or a particular document library?

Comment: all files in a document library

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
function CheckInDocument([string]$url)
{
    $spWeb = Get-SPWeb $url
    $getFolder = $spWeb.GetFolder("Shared Documents")
    $getFolder.Files | Where { $_.CheckOutStatus -ne "None" } | ForEach
    {
        Write-Host "$($_.Name) is Checked out To: $($_.CheckedOutBy)"
        $_.CheckIn("Checked In By Administrator")
        Write-Host "$($_.Name) Checked In" -ForeGroundColor Green
    }
    $spWeb.Dispose()
}
```

Here’s an example on running the function:

```
CheckInDocument http://SP
```

OR you can Try :

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb http://prinhyltphp0317/
$listName = "text"
$list = $spWeb.Lists |? {$_.Title -eq $listName}
foreach ($item in $list.Items) 
{
    $itemFile = $item.File
    if( $itemFile.CheckOutStatus -ne "None" )
    { 
        $itemFile.CheckIn("Automatic CheckIn. (Administrator)")
    }
}
$spWeb.Dispose()
```

Comment: and what are the parameters?  http://screencast.com/t/PcyNspl0

Comment: still not working, check screeenshot, script seems to have something wrong

Comment: Please share the screenshot.

Comment: lol see url above

Comment: I Have update the answer, You can try that and check if you still face issue

Answer (score 3):

This will also check all sub folders and check in if any file(s) are checked out

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://vm01"
$folder = $web.GetFolder("Style Library")
function GetFilesNuv($fldrs,$space){
    write-host $space -nonewline
    write-host $fldrs.name -backgroundcolor White -foregroundcolor Black
    $fldrs.Files | Where { $_.CheckOutStatus -ne "None" }  |ForEach-Object {
    write-host ($space,$_.Name,$_.CheckedOutBy) -Separator "  " -foregroundcolor Red
    $_.CheckIn("");
    }
    $fldrs.SubFolders |ForEach-Object {
    GetFilesNuv $_ ($space + "  ") ;
    }
}
GetFilesNuv $folder "  " 
$web.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution the so far the best as it goes through a web applications (including subfolders etc). Worked with SharePoint 2016 too.

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/02/find-all-checked-out-files-and-check-in.html

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Function CheckIn-AllCheckedOutFiles()
{  
    #Define 'Web Application URL' as Mandatory Parameter
    Param( 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$WebAppURL,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$ReportOutput
    )

    #Get the Web Application
    $WebApp = Get-SPWebApplication $WebAppURL

    #Write the CSV Header - Tab Separated
    "Site Collection Name `t Site Name`t Library `t File Name `t File URL `t  Last Modified `t Checked-Out By" | Out-file $ReportOutput

    #Arry to Skip System Lists and Libraries
    $SystemLists =@("Converted Forms", "Master Page Gallery", "Customized Reports", "Form Templates", "List Template Gallery", "Theme Gallery", 
           "Reporting Templates", "Solution Gallery", "Style Library", "Web Part Gallery","Site Assets", "wfpub")

    #Loop through each site collection
    ForEach($Site in $WebApp.Sites)
    {
        #Loop through each site in the site collection
        ForEach($Web in $Site.AllWebs)
        {
            Write-host "Processing Site:" $web.Url
            #Loop through each document library
            Foreach ($List in $Web.GetListsOfType([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseType]::DocumentLibrary))
            {
                #Get only Document Libraries & Exclude Hidden System libraries
                if ( ($List.Hidden -eq $false) -and ($SystemLists -notcontains $List.Title) )
                {
                    #Loop through each Item
                    foreach ($ListItem in $List.Items) 
                    {
                        If( ($ListItem.File.CheckOutStatus -ne "None") -and ($ListItem.File.CheckedOutByUser -ne $null))
                        {
                            #Log the data to a CSV file
                            "$($Site.RootWeb.Title) `t $($Web.Title) `t $($List.Title) `t $($ListItem.Name) `t $($Web.Url)/$($ListItem.Url) `t  $($ListItem['Modified'].ToString()) `t  $($ListItem.File.CheckedOutByUser)" | Out-File $ReportOutput -Append
                            Write-host -f Yellow "Found a Checked out file at: $($Web.Url)/$($ListItem.Url)"

                            #Check in the file
                            $ListItem.File.Checkin("Checked in by Administrator")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #Send message to output console
    write-host -f Green "Checked out Files Report Generated Successfully!"
}

#Call the Function to Get Checked-Out Files and check them in
CheckIn-AllCheckedOutFiles -WebAppURL "http://intranet.crescent.com" -ReportOutput "C:\Temp\CheckedOutFiles.txt"
```