# How to checkin SPCheckedOutFile

Tags: splistitem, check-out, check-in, spfile

In Powershell i get all checked out file from a library with

```
foreach($f in $lib.CheckedOutFiles){
    //I tried to retrieve item with 
    $item = $lib.GetItemById($f.ListItemID)//exception item not retrieve
}
```

How can i checkin spcheckedoutfile?

SOLUTION

I finally found a solution. For having item i have to do a TakeOverCheckOut before and after i can have item and file to checkin

```
foreach ($item in $lib.CheckedOutFiles) {
    write-Host $item.ListitemId
    $item.TakeOverCheckOut()//to retrieve item i have to do this before
    $doc = $lib.getItemById($item.ListitemId)
    $itemFile = $doc.File
    if($itemFile -ne $null){
        $itemFile.CheckIn("Checked In By Administrator for achive")
        write-Host " Checked In" -ForeGroundColor Green
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check-in all files within a specific library, try this

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb http://yoursite/
$splist = $spWeb.Lists |? {$_.Title -eq "libname"}
foreach ($item in $splist.Items) 
{
    if( $item.File.CheckOutStatus -ne "None" )
    { 
        $item.File.CheckIn("Checkedin")
    }
}
$spWeb.Dispose()
```

Check also [how to checkin all checked out files via powershell?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103610/how-to-checkin-all-checked-out-files-via-powershell)

Comment: Thanks but with this method you don't have files that has not yet checked in

Comment: I am sorry , but  what I understand from you , you need to check in all checked out files , should you elaborate more what  you need specifically , to can help you :) ?

Comment: Yes i use your solution for file already checked in in library but files that are not yet in library is not in items of library. You have to use .CheckedOutFiles.

Comment: Great job, thanks for this info :) ,  forgive me I think I didn't understand your question correctly at the first :) , So I answered based on this line in your quest  I get all checked out file from a library to check in